# Select Single DOM Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a eventlistener looking for a click on DOM elements with a certain class, and then changing innerHTML. It works, except it changes the innerHTML on all elements with the same class, and not just the one clicked. Is there a way to limit the scope to the element that was clicked, or do I need to give all the elements their own ID and call them based on IDs?

This is the function that I'm using:

```
$("button.accordion").click(function(){
    if ($(".caretUD").html("&#9660;")) {
            $(".caretUD").html("&#9650;");
    } else {
        console.log("I'm not working...");
    }
});
```

Comment: Please share your HTML with us. How are the buttons related to the carets?

Comment: `if ($(".caretUD").html("&#9660;")) {` i mean... like, that's not right. `.html("&#9660;")` will return `$(".caretUD")`, which is always going to be truthy, surely that's not what you intended.

Comment: We need your HTML so we can help.

Comment: When it comes to jQuery questions, you usually should provide some HTML for us to best help you. Our imaginations are not that strong yet.

Comment: you probably can get it by the `this` parameter... in this case `this` is probably with the scope of the clicked element

Comment: @CalvinNunes but `this` will be the button, not the caret

Comment: Please create a [mcve] - **HTML included!**

Comment: That's right, but is hard to identify without html

Comment: So you want what was clicked? So use this to get the reference to the button.... `$(this).html()`

Comment: @epascarello no, that's not what the OP wants

Comment: @Luca how is that so? "Is there a way to limit the scope to the element that was clicked" so that scope would be "this"......

Comment: ... Yes, that's what the OP is asking for. But that's clearly not what they want to do

Comment: @Luca I am glad you can decipher what the OP wants to do with the small question and lack of detail and HTML to back it up.

Comment: *It works, except it changes the innerHTML on all elements with the same class, and not just the one clicked.* If you are interested in changing the HTML of the clicked element, why is your click event attached to `button.accordion`, but your callback changes the HTML of `.caretUD`? Why not setup the `click` event on `.caretUD`?

Comment: @KevinB I misread the question, my bad.

Comment: @Luca I misread the question, my bad.

Comment: @Mikey I misread the question, my bad.

Comment: @ScottMarcus No worries. The question was unclear to begin with.

Comment: `if ($(".caretUD").html("&#9660;"))` should probably be `if ($(".caretUD").html() == "&#9660;")`

Comment: @epascarello He most likely wants to select either an element that's in the same container as as the one he clicked, or that's contained within the element he clicked. New jQuery users often assume that it will read their minds and select an element that's related to the clicked one like that.

Answer (score 0):

Is that helps ?
this is the current clicked element.

Notice that the event.currentTarget is the element where the event is recorded and this the element who fire the event (can be a child of the event.currentTarget or itself). In your case, with a button, it should be the same.

```
$("button.accordion").click(function(event) {
    if ($(this).html("&#9660;")) {
        $(this).html("&#9650;");
    } else {
        console.log("I'm not working...");
    }
});
```

Comment: This also does not change the HTML of the `.caretUD` element the OP wants to change the HTML of.

Comment: He want to change the clicked element "and not just the one clicked".

Comment: I think your answer is the closest as you are limiting the scope. I think it should be `$('.caretUD', this).html('&#9650;')` or `$(this).find('.caretUD').html('&#9650;')`. Though the IF condition by the OP makes no sense.

Comment: This depend on the need. If the button has the class caretUD, this will not work. I prefer let the OP choose what he wants about that.

Answer (score 0):

If `.caretUD` and `button.accordian` are both contained with the same container element, what you want is:

```
$("button.accordion").click(function() {
    var caret = $(this).closest(".container").find(".caretUD");
    if (caret.html() == "&#9660") {
        caret.html("&#9650;");
    } else {
        console.log("I'm not working");
    }
});
```

Replace `.container` with the actual class of the element that contains the button and the corresponding caret.

Answer (score -3):

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("button.accordion"); // get all the elements with a certain class
    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++){
        els[i].addEventListener('click',function(e){
            e.target.innerHTML = "something"; // e attribute is the key in this solution, as it gets the single DOM element that fired the event
        });
    }
```

**jQuery** solution:

```
$("button.accordion").click(function(){
    if ($(this).html() == "&#9660;") {
            $(this).html("&#9650;");
    } else {
        console.log("I'm not working...");
    }
});
```

Comment: My solution is properly working for me, don't know why you downvoted it :)

Comment: ...What? This just does the same thing as your prior answer, but without jQuery

Comment: It does exactly what he wants: change the innerHTML of the only clicked element..

Comment: "Is there a way to limit the scope to the element that was clicked, or do I need to give all the elements their own ID and call them based on IDs?" He never mentioned he wanted a jQuery solution.

Comment: Just posting code is a low-quality answer and will garner downvotes until an explanation of what you're doing and why is provided.  Furthermore, the question is tagged jQuery so he probably wants to continue using his platform of choice.

Comment: there you go with jquery solution